# How do I "playback" a MySQL log using its own timestamps?

Tags: mysql, performance-testing

I'm looking for a way to take a given MySQL log and reproduce the exact same transactions with the same time interval. So if I backed up a DB and captured logs with timestamps for 2 hours, I would then be able to restore it and make it happen over that same 2 hour period thus "playing" is back.

I've found a tool, Percona Toolkit, http://www.percona.com/software/percona-toolkit, but it seems to require very old libraries...

My goal is to simulate a specific and realistic load on our DB so developers can test some changes without causing problems with our production DB.

Any advice or tool recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you just looking for a way to make a backup or your database(s)?

Comment: Percona Toolkit is modern, maintained software. What old libraries are you referring to?